# Cannot add model instance to OneToManyField in django - "None has no attribute add"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I already have seen this bug in other post, but still in trouble.

I'm trying to create a social network like instagram where users will be able to publish posts (photos).
I have User class which herit from AbstractUser, and got a OneToMany field of posts: each user can publish many posts.

After successfully pulling my photo from: PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES) and saving it correctly, I cannot add this photo to the current user's publications/posts and got error:
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'`

```
def blog_and_photo_upload(request):
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = get_user(request) # user instance is correct with good pk
            post = Post.objects.create(image=form.cleaned_data['image']) # post instance looks correct also
            post.save()
            user.save()
            user.posts.add(post) # row doesnt work
            redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'base/upload_post.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    image = ResizedImageField(size=[300, 300], blank=True, upload_to='posts')
    

class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    posts = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.Cascade, null=True)
```

Comment: I don't see any field named `posts` in User model

Comment: I wrote the wrong row of my code. I just edited, user.posts is foreignkey from the Post class and i am in trouble to do: user.posts.add(post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply update the form like this:

```
post = Post.objects.create(image=form.cleaned_data['image']) # post instance looks correct also
post.save()
user.posts = post
user.save()
return redirect('home')
```

But, I think the design of the model is wrong, `User` to `Post` relation should be like this:

```
Class User(...):
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

In that way, your original implementation should work. (Probably you don't need `user.save()` call in your view).

Answer (score 1):

At first there should be `return redirect(...)` not only `redirect()` and secondly try to use the following view:

```py
def blog_and_photo_upload(request):
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = get_user(request) # user instance is correct with good pk
            post = Post.objects.create(image=form.cleaned_data['image']) # post instance looks correct also
            post.save()
            user.posts.add(post) # add post to user's posts field
            user.save()
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'base/upload_post.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind first Post with User model like add a ForeignKey or a ManyToManyFields to relate them

```py
posts = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

then you will be able to call it like you did

```py
user.posts # this won't return None
```

Check this many to many field docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I just edited the code, I wrote the wrong row. I already had posts which is a foreignKey from the Post class and cannot add post to user.posts